# Unwanted Linebreak in VBA-Variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, replace, line-breaks

I'm pretty much a newbie to VBA and Access and I start to get kinda frustrated.

I'm working on a program for calculating prizes and therefor I got HTML-Datas with the necessary informations which get split up as following:

```
strHTML = GetHTML(HTML)
List() = Split(strHTML, Chr(10))
```

Just to make it clear, the HTML lines I pick up for this look as following:

```
Motortyp=SM132
Motortypreihe=SM
MotorBG=132
MotorFE=35
MotorZusatz1=B
MotorZusatz2=
ReglerTyp=Fremdregler
```

So far so good.
The whole gear description (e.g. "SM200.15C") is taken at once and somehow there still is kind of a line break afterwards which leads to me not being able to use it in queries as I want to.

It seems like the line break at which I split up the HTML somehow is still present and it just don't want to get replaced by stuff like Replace([Data], Chr(10). "").

Hope the question was Kind of understandable since I got a few brain lags today.

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Comment: Try to replace with this: `Replace(Value, vbLf & vbCr, vbNullString)`

Comment: Replace(Value, vbNewLine, vbNullString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows a newline is obtained from the combination of a carriage return Chr(13) and linefeed Chr(10) characters. Use

```
List() = Split(strHTML, vbCrLf)
```

where `vbCrLf` is a VB constant representing this pair of characters.

Comment: Correct, although I would phrase it *"combination of a carriage return Chr(13) and line feed Chr(10)"*, to match the correct order in which they appear (it's crlf, not lfcr).

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi. I dimly recall having to supply them in 10+13 order in something like, maybe, MS Access, but this is probably just an historical artefact, an ancient quirk.